# How to validate Array object attribute if present in Karate

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, karate

What would be the proper way to create the match string in the case below?

I am stuck with the correct match string which would validate both of the below JSON(s).

In one of them, we have the "Periods" data,

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "period":
    [
        {
            "startDate": "2022-05-05",
            "endDate": "2022-05-06"
        },
        {
            "startDate": "2022-06-05",
            "endDate": "2022-06-06"
        }
    ]
}
```

on the other its a null array.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "period": []
}
```

I have been trying with the below match string but the same seems to fail

```
* match response contains deep "##({period: [{startDate: '#notnull'}]})"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def dateSchema = { startDate: '#string', endDate: '#string' }
* match response == { id: '#number', period: '#[] dateSchema' }
```

Comment: Thank you @peter. This worked marvelously.

made a minor change to match
* match response == { id: '#number', period: '##[] dateSchema' }
to cater the scenario if the key is not sent.

Thank you.